# Python multi module global variables. A bug in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, global-variables

Recently I set up this example and am surprised by the results. I will demonstrate this with code:

File1: **b.py**:

```
delta = 0.0

def example():
    global delta

    delta = 1

def ret_delta():
    return delta
```

File2: **a.py**:

```
from b import *

example()

#WHY ARE THESE DIFFERENT?
print(delta) # prints: 0.0
print(ret_delta()) # prints: 1
```

This doesn't make sense! Why would accessing the variable and calling a function that returns that variable make any difference?

For your reference I am using python 3.5.2 on Windows 32 bit

Comment: `from b import *` is bad form (and obscuring what happens in this situation is one of the reasons). Consider `import b` and using `b.delta` instead. This is both more explicit, _and_ will actually work as you expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

`from b import *`

in `a.py`, it imports all names defined in the module `b` (including `delta`) into `a`'s namespace. As `float` in an immutable type in Python, you can consider `a.delta` a completely separate variable from `b.delta`, pointing to a different value.
 Thus, the first `print()` prints the initial value of `a.delta`, while the second prints the updated value of `b.delta`.

Answer (score 1):

`from b import *` creates a series of new references in your `a` module globals. Each one of those copies the reference from `b` name. They are *independent* globals however.

Remember that in Python, names are merely *labels*; they are 'tied' to objects. You create this relationship by assignment, and you can create more than one label per object. That's what is happening here, you have labels in `b` and labels in `a`, and after `from b import *` the labels in both modules refer to the same objects.

However, you then assign a **different object** to the `delta` name in `b`. Now that label is no longer referencing the old `0.0` float object. But you didn't alter what the `delta` label in `a` is tied to.

If you were to prefix the names with the module name, you'd get `a.delta` and `b.delta`; the assignment `b.delta = 1` wouldn't alter `a.delta`, they live in different namespaces.

You may want to read up on how Python names work; see the excellent [*Facts and myths about Python names and values* presentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Your clause in answer confuse me.  In  |, and after from b import a they refer to the same objects|, from b import a? Is that right?

Comment: @EkeymeMo: I'm not sure I follow your comment, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was writen on phone, I cannot insert the highlight featrue. In your answer you say `and after from b import a they refer to the same objects`, I think what you want to say is  `... from b import * ...`. Is that right?

Comment: @EkeymeMo: yes, that was a typo on my part.